# Powershell - Mulitple Servers CPU/Mem/C Drive stats - Total Average

Tags: powershell

Newbie here, :-)

Hope you all well and to reach out for some assistance;

I have a code also which can generate CPU/Mem/C Drive stats for multiple servers, and was hoping to ask for help if this could have a total average of all the servers? with the script below, is there a way to include getting the total average of all the servers I have gathered (e.g. 10 servers)?

```
$ServerListFile = "D:\serverList.txt"  
$ServerList = Get-Content $ServerListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$Result = @() 
ForEach($computername in $ServerList) 
{

$AVGProc = Get-WmiObject -computername $computername win32_processor | 
Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average
$OS = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $computername |
Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }}
$vol = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Volume -ComputerName $computername -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'" |
Select-object @{Name = "C PercentFree"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f  (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity)*100) } }

$result += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
ServerName = "$computername"
CPULoad = "$($AVGProc.Average)%"
MemLoad = "$($OS.MemoryUsage)%"
CDrive = "$($vol.'C PercentFree')%"
}
$Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> Server Health Report </TITLE>
             <BODY background-color:peachpuff>
             <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le"">
             <H2> Server Health Report </H2></font>
             <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
             <TR bgcolor=gray align=center>
               <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD>
               <TD><B>Avrg.CPU Utilization</B></TD>
               <TD><B>Memory Utilization</B></TD>
               <TD><B>Drive C Free Space</B></TD>
               </TR>"

Foreach($Entry in $Result) 

    { 
  if(($Entry.CpuLoad) -or ($Entry.memload) -ge "80") 
  { 
    $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=white>" 
  } 
  else
   {
    $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
  }
  $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CPULoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.MemLoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CDrive)</TD></TR>" 
}
 $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
 } 

$Outputreport | out-file "D:\Result $(Get-Date -Format yyy-mm-dd-hhmm).htm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have all the numbers available in the `$Result` array, you could simply pipe it to `Measure-Object` to get the average.

The problem is that you've turned the orginal numerical values into strings and postfixed the percentage sign `%`. Use `Select-Object` to turn remove the `%` so we can treat the values as numbers again:

```
$CPUAvg = $Result |Select-Object @{Label='CPU';Expr={$_.CPULoad -replace '%'}} |Measure-Object CPU -Average |Select-Object -Expand Average
$MemAvg = $Result |Select-Object @{Label='Mem';Expr={$_.MemLoad -replace '%'}} |Measure-Object Mem -Average |Select-Object -Expand Average
$CDriveAvg = $Result |Select-Object @{Label='CDrive';Expr={$_.CDrive -replace '%'}} |Measure-Object CDrive -Average |Select-Object -Expand Average
```

---

Please be aware that this comparison:

```
($Entry.memload) -ge "80"
```

Will yield unexpected results for the same reason mentioned above.

When comparing strings, `"9" -ge "80"` will yield `$true` - probably not what you expected

Comment: Hi Mathias,Thanks for your response; Unfortunately I'm getting no value on the result, and what I'm seeing on the test result is, inserting another row to each server it gets.  It may probably where I place your code; still unsure, why it is returning an empty value.

Comment: Also, will I be able to convert it back to percentage upon displaying the result?  should I be using

    LoadPercentage -Average

or just plain

    "$($CPUAve)%"